LCD TV as a second monitor not working on Ubuntu 24.04.1
I am using Ubuntu, dual-booted with Windows 11, on a Dell laptop with Nvidia GTX 3050 GPU. I tried to connect my LCD TV to my laptop using HDMI. At first it wasn't even detecting it, so I installed a Nvidia driver 550. After rebooting the laptop, the screen was all black.
I removed the Nvidia drivers using the root shell prompt in "additional options for Ubuntu" option at boot. Then I don't know how the laptop detected the HDMI port, but the screen was half-grey/half-color.
The TV is working properly with Windows.
How do I configure TV for Ubuntu?
